# anchor tag onclick not working

Tags: javascript, anchor

I am creating anchor tags in a list using javascript, but the onClick is not firing. I know the function being called by the onClick works, since I tested it with a makeshift submit button to test, but I need the anchor tags to call it. This is my code.

```
function getTablePages(div,pages,index){
index -= 1;
var mydiv;
switch (div){
    case 'openSales': mydiv = document.getElementById("openSalesDiv"); break;
    case 'leadsSales': mydiv = document.getElementById("leadsSalesDiv"); break;
    case 'overdueTickets': mydiv = document.getElementById("overdueTicketsDiv"); break;
    case 'readyToBill': mydiv = document.getElementById("readyToBillDiv"); break;
    case 'overdueSales': mydiv = document.getElementById("overdueSalesDiv"); break;
    case 'overdueProjects': mydiv = document.getElementById("overdueProjectsDiv"); break;
    case 'wfcTickets': mydiv = document.getElementById("wfcTicketsDiv"); break;
    case 'openTickets': mydiv = document.getElementById("openTicketsDiv"); break;
    case 'assignedPM':  mydiv = document.getElementById("assignedPMDiv");
}
var ulTag = document.createElement('ul');
ulTag.className = 'Pagination';
ulTag.style = 'display:block;';
var liTag = document.createElement('li');
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"#");
aTag.innerHTML = "<";
liTag.appendChild(aTag);
ulTag.appendChild(liTag);
for (v = 0; v < pages; v++){
    if(v+6 >= index && v < index+5){
        var liTag = document.createElement('li');
        var aTag = document.createElement('a');
        aTag.setAttribute('href',"#");
        switch (div){
            case 'openSales': aTag.onClick = "getOpenSalesClick(this.innerHTML)"; break;
            case 'leadsSales': aTag.onClick = "getleadsSalesClick(this.innerHTML)"; break;
            case 'overdueTickets': aTag.onClick = "getOverdueTicketsClick(this.innerHTML)"; break;
            case 'readyToBill': aTag.onClick = "getReadyToBillProjectsClick(this.innerHTML)"; break;
            case 'overdueSales': aTag.onClick = "getOverdueSalesClick(this.innerHTML)"; break;
            case 'overdueProjects': aTag.onClick = "getOverdueProjectsClick(this.innerHTML)"; break;
            case 'wfcTickets': aTag.onClick = "getWFCTicketsClick(this.innerHTML)"; break;
            case 'openTickets': aTag.onClick = "getOpenTicketsClick(this.innerHTML)"; break;
            case 'assignedPM':  aTag.onClick = "getAssignedPMClick(this.innerHTML)";
        }
        aTag.innerHTML = (v+1);
        liTag.appendChild(aTag);
        ulTag.appendChild(liTag);
    }
}
    var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"#");
aTag.innerHTML = ">";
liTag.appendChild(aTag);
ulTag.appendChild(liTag);
mydiv.appendChild(ulTag);
}

function getOpenSalesClick(x){
document.getElementById('openSalesDiv').innerHTML = '';
}

<input type='submit' onclick="getOpenSalesClick()" value="Delete"></input>
```

Comment: aTag.innerHTML = "<"; // < is invalid HTML

Comment: You sure? Cause when I run the program all my anchor tags show up, including the "<" one, just the onclick function isn't working.

Comment: Use `.textContent` instead if you are setting text

Comment: are you talking about .textContent inside my onclick function call or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers tend to be lowercase in JavaScript. Try `onclick` instead of `onClick`. The `onclick` handler also needs to reference a function not a string, and presumably you want the function `getOpenSalesClick` to be called on each click rather than the result of `getOpenSalesClick()`:

```
case 'openSales': aTag.onclick = getOpenSalesClick;
```

Comment: I had that at first and it didn't work, just changed it to onClick right before posting to see if that was the problem, but it's not.

Comment: `onclick` also need to reference a function not a string

Comment: case 'openSales': aTag.onclick = getOpenSalesClick(this.innerHTML); break;

Comment: Well what does `getOpenSalesClick` do? Does it return your click handler function or is that what you want to call on the click event itself? Try this: `case 'openSales': aTag.onclick = getOpenSalesClick.bind(null, this.innerHTML); `

Comment: It deletes the innerHTML from the div, but like I said, I know the function works cause I have set up a button with an onclick to call it to test it out and it works. Just need it to be called from the anchor tags and not from the button. So the problem doesn't lie within the function itself.

Comment: Can you add `getOpenSalesClick` and the test button click handler code to your question?

Comment: Yea I did. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: `case 'openSales': aTag.onclick = getOpenSalesClick;`

Comment: That works! But now if I want to pass the innerHTML value with the function, how would I do that with it working, since that is my end goal.. The erase the innerHTML function was just for test purposes. I want it to delete the div but then replace it based on what value gets passed back.

Comment: Then you would have to bind the function to the arguments as per my previous comment: `case 'openSales': aTag.onclick = getOpenSalesClick.bind(null, this.innerHTML);`

Comment: I found a much quicker way, just have to add this line of code inside the function itself     var index = this.innerHTML;

Comment: Thanks for the help though, much appreciated.

Comment: Actually yeah that is better because an event handler gets the DOM element as its function context by default